# Why Windows10 64bit sees only 4GB RAM on 8GB installed?

Tags: windows, memory

Scenario:

- Windows Home edition 64bit
- RAM: 2x4GB DDR2 800mhz
- Motherboard: Foxcon Q45M (Intel Q45/Q43)(up to 16GB RAM 4x4GB slot)
- CPUZ sees 2x4GB modules

Problem:

The Bios sees 2x4GB = 8GB RAM but Windows sees only 4GB RAM

What I checked (as suggested here: [enter link description here](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask?title=Why%20Windows10%2064bit%20sees%20only%204GB%20RAM%20on%208GB%20installed%3F)) :

1. Turn off Auto RAM Virtualization (done)
2. Check if your RAM is properly seated (done)
3. Check if your RAM is faulty (done)
4. Rearrange your RAM modules (done)
5. Change your BIOS settings:

   - Vitualization – ON.
   - iGPU – OFF.
   - Render Stability – Enabled
   - iGPU memory – Auto
6. Use msconfig (done)
7. Check if your RAM is compatible with your motherboard (done)
8. Check if you have integrated graphics (done)
9. Check if BIOS recognizes your RAM (done)

[image: screenshot]

any tips?
thx

Comment: I also tryed to install 4x4GB RAM, in this case windows sees only 8GB

Comment: Have you checked for bios updates?

Comment: Literally the first words on our site - "Server Fault is a question and answer site for managing information technology systems in a business environment"....

Comment: Do you think the problem could be due to Windows Home edition? This is a stand alone workstation in a business environment

Comment: No, Home can address 128GB

Comment: As you tried 4 x 4GB and Windows saw *8GB* (and it therefore can see that much), I would try using a different slot for the second module.

Comment: I don't see your graphic card mentioned.  If it is onboard, it is certainly using SOME of it.  I would also suggest booting a linux live USB stick and see what IT says.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Foxcomm MB has not bios update anymore, so I have to accept a max of 6GB RAM (2x2+2x1) 
Thx for help